# SHARE method is sending old versions of data

Tags: javascript, share

I have an online word game site I'm developing for fun. I recently added sharing of puzzle completion, using Javascript. It works fine and the shared result is what I expected.

However if I reset the puzzle and complete it again the data sent through SHARE is the first set of data with the first score, not the second.

```
s = "I just finished the Addergram puzzle for " + this.fileName().substring(0,11) + "\n\n"
  + "I scored " + this.totalScore + " %"
  + "\n\n"
  + s;
//console.log(s);
const shareData = {
  title: "Addergrams",
  text: s,
  url: "https://addergrams.com",
};
```

In the code segment above, s is a multi-line string showing emojis reflecting puzzle state. As I say, it's all working fine the first time but subsequent shares send the stale data. When not commented out, console.log shows that the data is being reconstructed correctly - does the SHARE api require any action to reset the data before sending again ?

For completeness the event listener on the SHARE button is defined as ...

```
btn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
    await navigator.share(shareData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Edited to add data ...

Opened the page in a fresh browser tab (Edge on Windows 11) and ran 2 passes completing the puzzle differently, results below.

**Pass 1 ...**

```
Logged to console ...
I just finished the Addergram puzzle for 07-SEP-2023

I scored 46 %







⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫

Shared to GMAIL ...
Addergrams
https://addergrams.com/
I just finished the Addergram puzzle for 07-SEP-2023

I scored 46 %







⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
```

**So far so good.

Pass 2 ...**

```
Logged to console ... (correct)

I just finished the Addergram puzzle for 07-SEP-2023

I scored 6 %

⚫⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫


Shared to GMAIL ... (incorrect)
Addergrams
https://addergrams.com/
I just finished the Addergram puzzle for 07-SEP-2023

I scored 46 %







⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
```

The string is definitely being constructed fresh with each puzzle iteration. That string is fed into the shareData construct, which is passed to the event listener, but it's not shared.

A thought occurs to me. The event listener is bound to the button at each pass, but is the second pass not rebinding because the event from the first pass is still bound ?

Edit 2
I made shareData a parameter of the main gameboard class, updated the text into there and changed the event listener to...

```
btn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
    await navigator.share(this.shareData);
  } catch (err) {
```

Result - problem solved.

Comment: Please post a link to whatever `SHARE` library you use

Comment: @mplungjan [It's a native API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share).

Comment: @RhythMick Are you sure the issue isn't that you predefine your string once and then reuse the same old string every time the share button is clicked, even if state changed in between? (I know you wrote the console shows the correct string, which is odd, but just from looking at your code it seems this may be an issue, so maybe you could double-check...)

Comment: @mplungjan - it's the standard built-in navigator.share (see code snippet)

Comment: @CherryDT - yeah thanks I checked that thoroughly. Each time the puzzle is completed the function executes, declares the string s, constructs it, logs it to console and uses it in the navigator.share. The console shows s is different each time, but the data shared is stale.

Comment: Thanks for contributions and help @CherryDT. This time I solved it myself (love it when that happens) but so much appreciate the willingness of talented people around the world to jump in and help. Brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it as follows... Hoping it helps someone else.

I made shareData a parameter of the main gameboard class, updated the text into there and changed the event listener to...

```html
btn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
    await navigator.share(this.shareData);
  } catch (err) {
```

Result - problem solved. In short, when I bound the event listener using a locally constructed variable, that variable was (obviously) statically bound within the event listener. By storing the shareData into a parameter of the singleton class object and passing that into the event listener function the data can be updated with each pass.